# Exception : java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java, linux, jboss, wildfly

Hi I am getting the below error

```
Exception : java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
```

I am in the process of moving from geronimo 2.1 to wildfly 8

During the testing of the new application server we get this error. Nothing else had changed exactly the same web appliations running and we have never had this issue on **Geronimo**.

Any ideas?

Thanks

TOm

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your new application server is "fd-happy".

What you need to do to make it work is to configure your system so that the limit on the number of file descriptors for the application server be raised.

Identify the user running the webapp container; let us say it is "flint". When done, add this line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
flint hard nofiles 4096
```

Since a usual limit to the number of open files is 1024, this will quadruple it.

On more recent distributions, there is also an `/etc/security/limits.d` directory: you may want to create a file in there instead and put the line above in it.

Edit: for a given user, you can query the current limit on the number of open files using `ulimit -n`; try `ulimit -a` to see all currently defined limitations.

Edit 2: if you have raised the "nofile limit" and still see the error after some running time, you have a bug -- somewhere...